# How do I solve this error: ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier

Tags: php, sql, oracle, yii2, yii2-active-records

I have a view in my schema that lists the staff information.

I want to calculate the RETIRE_DATE from these two fields: BIRTH_DATE and RETIRE_AGE.

Using the `RETIRE_DATE` I want to query the staff retiring in a certain period.

Running the query gives me an error

> ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier

I think it's beacuse I am using the `RETIRE_DATE` as a column of my view in the query. How do I correct this?

Here's my code:

```
    $start_period = strtotime("-100 week");
    $stop_period = strtotime("+100 week");

    $query = StaffEmploymentListView::find()
        ->SELECT([
          'PAYROLL_NO', 
          'BIRTH_DATE',
          'RETIRE_AGE',
          "ADD_MONTHS(BIRTH_DATE, RETIRE_AGE * 12) AS RETIRE_DATE"]);
    
    $query->andFilterWhere(['>=',$this->RETIRE_DATE, $start_period])
            ->andFilterWhere(['<=', $this->RETIRE_DATE, $stop_period])
            ->all();
```

My table looks like below:
[image]

Comment: can you provide an example of the data stored in that table ? and also which data type is retire_age ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the query, but with the quotation

Comment: @RobertoHernandez I have included a photo of how my table looks like. The retire_age is of type NUMBER(2,0)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some information on the error:

ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier

**Cause: An attempt was made to use two double quotes ("") as an identifier. An identifier must be at least one character long.**

Your query has a problem in the way you are quoting the elements. I made a test using oci_connect and oci_execute, and I have no issues.

Perhaps you need to rewrite it as follows, or use the same quotation for all elements. In your case you are quoting some columns with `'` , and the last part with `"`

```
<?php
$conn = oci_connect("username","password","database");

$query = "SELECT
           PAYROLL_NO, 
           BIRTH_DATE,
           RETIRE_AGE,
           ADD_MONTHS(BIRTH_DATE, RETIRE_AGE * 12) AS RETIRE_DATE 
          FROM YOUR_TABLE_OR_VIEW";


$stmt = oci_parse($conn,$query);
oci_execute($stmt);
?>
```

Comment: I am using the calculated RETIRE_DATE as an identifier in my query. My view has no column called RETIRE_DATE. Converting my query above into a raw  SQL I get this:                SELECT "PAYROLL_NO", "BIRTH_DATE", ADD_MONTHS(BIRTH_DATE, 70 * 12) AS RETIRE_DATE FROM "HRMIS"."STAFF_EMPLOYLIST_VIEW" WHERE ("" >= :qp0) AND ("" <= :qp1)                                                                                                                                  The  RETIRE_DATE is not put in WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this part of your code

```php
$query->andFilterWhere(['>=',$this->RETIRE_DATE, $start_period])
    ->andFilterWhere(['<=', $this->RETIRE_DATE, $stop_period])
    ->all();
```

If you put it like that, the `$this->RETIRE_DATE` is evaluated and the value of `RETIRE_DATE` property is used. Because the property is empty the resulting condition will be something like `"" >= $start_period`.

The condition you've probably wanted is something like this `RETIRE_DATE >= $start_period`. To achieve that you need to pass `RETIRE_DATE` into `andFilterWhere` as string instead of passing value of `RETIRE_DATE` property.

```php
$query->andFilterWhere(['>=', 'RETIRE_DATE', $start_period])
    ->andFilterWhere(['<=', 'RETIRE_DATE', $stop_period])
    ->all();
```

Comment: Changing that part of my query I get this error: ORA-00904 ERROR MESSAGE “INVALID IDENTIFIER”. There's no column called RETIRE_DATE in my view. It's a calculated value in the SELECT query above.

Comment: @rufusy That's probably because you can't use calculated fields in where clause. In mysql you can use them in having clause but i don't have enough experience with oracle to say what is best way to do it there. If you want to try the having clause just change `andFilterWhere` methods to `andFilterHaving`.